# Getting errors while configuration of ChatCamp Sdk and importing sample project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

****While configuring

> ChatCamp

SDK with my project with compileSdkVersion 25 I get sync error****

> Error:(33, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'
>   Possible causes:
>
> The project 'ChatCamp' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
>   Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.1 and sync project
>
> The project 'ChatCamp' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>   Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
>   Apply Gradle plugin

***with compile sdk 26***

> Error:(33, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'
>   Possible causes:
>
> The project 'ChatCamp' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
>   Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.1 and sync project
>
> The project 'ChatCamp' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>   Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
>   Apply Gradle plugin

***When import

> Sample Project*** in 
>   ***Android Studio 2.3.1***

sample project gradle version 4.1
Android Plugin |Version  3.0.1
Error:This Gradle plugin requires a newer IDE able to request IDE model level 3. For Android Studio this means version 3.0+

***If changes > Sample App
 gradle version 4.1 to 3.4.1 and android plugin version 3.0.1 to 2.3.1
then I get-***

> Error:(6, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'
>   Possible causes:
>
> The project 'ChatCamp-Android-Example-master' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
>   Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.1 and sync project
>
> The project 'ChatCamp-Android-Example-master' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>   Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
>   Apply Gradle plugin

Comment: Can you reduce your question to a less verbose and cluttered question? There is so much information about what you are doing, "possible causes" and ways out of them,....

Comment: Post your build.gradle pls

Answer (score 2):

You are facing this problem because the sample https://github.com/ChatCamp/ChatCamp-Android-Example is using gradle version greater than 3.0.0. There were some breaking changes in Gradle 3.0.0. You can take a look at how to migrate to new version of gradle [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html) .
If you want to run [this sample](https://github.com/ChatCamp/ChatCamp-Android-Example) in older version of gradle you just need to replace **implementation** with **compile**, **testImplementation** with **testCompile** and **androidTestImplementation** with **androidTestCompile**.

Comment: Thank you! Shubham!